# Unable to pass variable arguments to dplyr using a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am unable to pass variable arguments to `dplyr` using a function. A mock version of the function is

```
Fun.function(data, var.1, var.2) {
data %>% 
group_by_(var.1) %>%
summarise_(mean.var.2 = mean(var.2))
}
```

The error is

> Error: Index out of bounds

It will be great if someone can help me with this.

Comment: See NSE vignette of dplyr package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read through the [NSE vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) you can see that you would need lazy evaluation of the functions you use inside your function. Using my example below you need to put the variables in quotes.

Looking at your function you are trying to do the following, using mtcars as an example:

```
  mtcars %>%
        group_by_(~ cyl) %>%
        summarise_(mean.var.2 = ~mean(mpg))
```

To turn this into your function you need to do the following and put the variables in quotes when you call the function.

```
f <- function(data, var.1, var.2) {
      data %>% 
            group_by_(lazyeval::interp(~ var, var = as.name(var.1))) %>% 
            summarise_(mean.var.2 = lazyeval::interp(~mean(var), var = as.name(var.2)))
}

 f(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg")
  cyl mean.var.2
1   4   26.66364
2   6   19.74286
3   8   15.10000
```

To check if they are identical to just using dplyr commands

```
identical(
      f(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg"),
      mtcars %>%
            group_by_(~ cyl) %>%
            summarise_(mean.var.2 = ~mean(mpg))
)
[1] TRUE
```